Ansible replace: regex/replace multiple lines?
In ansible, I'd like to replace this:
pgsql:
  useCluster: false
  addr: 127.0.0.1:5432
  password: ""
email:
  to: xxx@gmail.com
  port: 465
  password: ""

replace to this:
pgsql:
  useCluster: false
  addr: 127.0.0.1:5432
  password: "2024xxx"
email:
  to: xxx@gmail.com
  port: 465
  password: ""

Because there are two identical variables that cannot be replaced,I use this method.But it cannot be achieved. How should everyone handle it?
replace:
      path: "config.yaml"
      regexp: '(redis:[^<]*)password: ""'
      replace: '\1password: "2024xxx"'


You might want to check out the ansible module for editing yml files. https://github.com/kwoodson/ansible-role-yedit

Use template Ansible module instead of  replace.
Manually edit the source document to have Jinja expressions where the values should be.
pgsql:
  useCluster: false
  addr: 127.0.0.1:5432
  password: "{{ thing_pgsql_password | default('') }}"
email:
  to: xxx@gmail.com
  port: 465
  password: "{{ thing_email_password | default('') }}"

Where thing is a short prefix for your organization or project, making names less likely to collide.  And the variable name is from some secret storage lookup, given it is a password. default filter at the end is optional, depending on if you want a value if the variable is not defined, or an error.
    - template:
        src: config.yml
        dest: /etc/whatever/config.yml

template module is different in that it has to render the source file on localhost, the Ansible controller. If you previously relied on the remote host containing values in this file, you may want to adjust to the managed host not being the source of truth anymore.

This cannot be done using templates. Is there a way to replace it?

Probably, however I will not write regular expressions for you, or in general recommend managing part of a file. Edit your question to clarify why you must replace an existing file if you want other answers.
